# Defining more than one operation on the set so that with respect to every one of the operations the set is a group

Tags: group-theory

I guess this could be a hard question but since I am no expert, and I am not even close to an expert I really do not know.

The basic idea is that we start with some group $(G,*)$. Because $(G,*)$ is a group it has over itself defined operation $*$ which satisfies all the group axioms.

Now, suppose that we take the set $G$ and that we seek to find another operation $o$ such that $(G,o)$ is also a group.

It seems to me that for some sets we will be able to find another operation under which the set is a group and for some sets we will not (but I may be mistaken).

So the question would be:

> Are there any necessary, or sufficient, or necessary and sufficient conditions on the set $G$, or on the set $G$ and operation $*$, such that under these conditions there exist (or do not exist) at least one more operation (call it $o$) such that $(G,o)$ is also a group? What is known on these matters?

Comment: If $|G|>1$ then there will be more than one such operation. There must be at least $|G|$ of them, because any of the elements of $G$ could be made into the identity element.

Comment: @DerekHolt Hi Derek, could you elaborate a little more on that and write it as an answer, if you wish to?

Comment: More interesting is asking for the other structure to not be isomorphic to the original.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft I am at the first page of some book that has to do with group theory, it could be that I will have more interesting questions if I go more into the theory of groups, right now I only learned the definition of the group.

Comment: Another question is: how do the two operations *interact*? The problem is "easier" if the operations have "nothing to do with each other", but then far less "useful". What Derek is suggesting is just a "re-labeling" of the elements (and we can use any set-bijection to accomplish this).

Comment: Re-learned, because I knew it before.

Answer (score 3):

Every group structure $(S,*)$ on a set of cardinality $n$ gives rise to up to $n!$ other isomorphic group structures, given by transfer of structure: pick a bijection $f:S\to S$ and define $s\circ s'=f{-1}(f(s)f(s'))$. There are $n!$ choices of $f$, and $\circ$ is distinct from $*$ if and only if $f$ is not a homomorphism for $*$, so this gives $n!/|\text{Aut}S|$ total structures. Derek's comment points out that this quantity is at least $n$, since automorphisms of $S$ must preserve the identity (so that the automorphism group has order at most $(n-1)!$), but this bound is almost never tight for groups of order larger than 2. For example, cyclic groups of prime order $p$ have exactly $p-1$ automorphisms, so there are $p(p-2)!$ distinct cyclic group structures on a set of order $p$.

Comment: The bound on the automorphism group of a group of order $n$ having order at most $(n-1)$! is tight for the cyclic group of order $3$ and the Klein group. (In both cases, any permutation fixing the identity is an automorphism.)

Comment: @verret ah yes, thanks.